# How to translate a WordPress.org plugin?

Tags: translation

WordPress.org launched recently a new translation mechanism via https://translate.wordpress.org/.

What steps should I make to translate a plugin at wp.org plugin repository correctly?

Can I remove the .po/.mo/.pot files from the plugins folder?

Are the .po/.mo translations already included into the plugin's translations on https://translate.wordpress.org/ website?

Is it possible to translate theme via this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to make plugin translatable via [translate.wordpress.org](https://translate.wordpress.org/) you need to add text domain into main plugin's file:

```
/*
 * Plugin Name: My Plugin
 * Author: Plugin Author
 * Text Domain: my-plugin
 */
```

So to make theme translatable via [translate.wordpress.org](https://translate.wordpress.org/) you need to add text domain into main theme's file:

```
/*
* Theme Name: My Theme
* Author: Theme Author
* Text Domain: my-theme
*/
```

And also all the strings should be wrapped with gettext _() functions with the same text domain.

All further details can be found in the official docs below:

- [translate.wordpress.org](https://translate.wordpress.org/)
- [how-to-internationalize-your-plugin](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/internationalization/how-to-internationalize-your-plugin/)
- [theme internationalization](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/internationalization/)